# query the index of a variable

Tags: sqlite

Suppose I have an sqlite database containing a table `mytable` with a single variable `myvariable` and suppose I've created an index `myindex` to speed up queries on `myvariable`.  Sometimes I want to work with `myvariable` but I don't care about it's actual values -- I only care about its sequence of unique values.  It's pretty easy to query `myvariable` and create a unique index for it afterwards, but I wonder if it's possible to skip that step by directly querying `myindex`.  It could look something like this:

```
SELECT myvariable, myindex FROM mytable
```

but of course this fails.

Comment: Actually, I don't know how myindex would look.  I was assuming it would be a sequence of integer values.  Possibly the only benefit to doing this would be to reduce myvariable to something more lightweight in case myvariable consists of enormous character strings.

Comment: Please show some example data and the desired output.